# How to import types from Firebase Admin Node.js SDK?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to import the `DecodedIDToken` type (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.decodedidtoken) so that I can assign a type to the value in the `.then()` callback for when I verify an ID token via `admin.auth().verifyIdToken()`.

I'm unable to import the `DecodedIDToken` type from `firebase-admin` and I'm not sure what exactly the issue is. Is it because only `admin` is exported from the `firebase-admin` module?

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

const isAuthenticated = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { authorization } = req.headers;

    if (authorization == null || !authorization.startsWith("Bearer")) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
    }

    const split = authorization.split("Bearer ");
    if (split.length !== 2) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
    }

    const token = split[1];

    try {
        admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
        .then((decodedIdToken: DecodedIDToken) => {
            req.userIdToken = decodedIdToken;
        })
        .catch();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error: " + error);
    }
}

export default isAuthenticated;
```

Comment: Also it's `DecodedIdToken` and not `DecodedIDToken`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DecodedIdToken` is exported from Firebase Admin *Auth* SDK.

```
import { DecodedIdToken } from "firebase-admin/auth";
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error: `Cannot find module 'firebase-admin/auth' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`. I have the following as part of my `package.json`:

`
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^9.6.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
  }
`

Might I be missing a package or import?

Answer (score 0):

Just try it:

```
import { DecodedIdToken } from 'firebase-admin/lib/auth/token-verifier';
```